# How to change the name of a Mac application in the build settings?

Tags: cocoa, macos, app-store, application-name

I am about to submit an app to the Mac App Store, however the name of my application conflicts with another application in their system. So I picked another name and I tried to change the name of my application by going into the build settings under the "Packaging" section and "Product Name" row. I cleaned all targets and rebuilt the application, but the name displayed in the menu bar and bundle was the old name.

What I am missing? How do I change the name of an application without having to recreate another project?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you are editing the Product Name of the target not the Project. So the menu `Project->Edit Active Target "targetname"` not `Project->Edit Project Settings`. Or right-click on the target in the group list and choose `Get Info`.

Note that you will have to edit MainMenu.xib to show the correct app name in the About, Quit, and Help menu items.

Comment: Thanks I also went to Project -> Rename.

Comment: How to localize that name?